# How to make an exception in jQuery's .click() and .submit()

Tags: php, jquery

I have the code below:

```
 $("#sub").click( function() {
     $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
             $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
             function(info){ $("#result").html(info); 
       });

 });

$("#myForm").submit( function() {
  return false;    
});
```

But I want a certain element to be echoed out from my PHP script that the code is being used for prior to any submit or click.  Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: `prior to any submit or click`: so it's not an exception from the two handlers, it's another event, Just put the code outside the click and submit. Or you mean after the click and before the $.post() ?

Comment: Clarifying your question a little bit more will help us to help you

Comment: I think he needs to echo out message using server side execution prior to client-side code execution? Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: Yeah that's what I need to do.